# Using Jquery Highlight

Tags: jquery, html, highlight

Im in a spot of bother trying to get this Jquery highlight to work within my current project, i have a textbox where the user enters a mobile phone number they want to within a HTML table when they click the button i was the Jquery highlight to kick in and highlight all mobile numbers that match the criteria the user entered but for somereason it doesnt seem to be working nor does it throw an error?!?! can some one help me please.

```
 $('#<%= BtnFindMobile.ClientID %>').click(function () {
            var phonenumber = $('#<%= txtSearchMobile.ClientID %>').val();
            $('#grdvHandSets td.highlight').removeClass('highlight'). // Clear existing highlights
            // Find matching phonenumber fields
            find('input.phonenumber').filter(function () {
            return $(this).val() == phonenumber;
            }).
            closest('td').addClass('highlight'); // And highlight these cells
            return false;
         });
```

heres the html table and its the second TD i want to reference the mobile phone column "txtMobileNumber", the CSS for the hight light has been set as a background-color: red;

```
 <span class="AddressLabel">Search Mobile:</span><asp:TextBox ID="txtSearchMobile"
                                  runat="server" MaxLength="11" Style="width: 90px !important"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;&nbsp
                              <asp:Button ID="BtnFindMobile" runat="server" Text="Find" /></p>


<table cellspacing="0" id="grdvHandSets" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">R</th><th scope="col">MobileNumber</th><th scope="col">Type</th><th scope="col">PortingFrom</th><th scope="col">Username</th><th scope="col">Type of use</th><th scope="col">Tariff Name</th><th scope="col">Tariff Code</th><th scope="col">SOC Name</th><th scope="col">SOC Code</th><th scope="col">Contract Term</th><th scope="col">Handset Description</th><th scope="col">Phone Cover</th><th scope="col">PAC Code</th><th scope="col">Con Date</th><th scope="col">X</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>                   
                              <span id="lblRowNumber" class="gvItem">1</span>                                   
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input name="ctl00$MainContent$OrderTabs$tbDefaultOrder$grdvHandSets$ctl02$txtMobileNumber" type="text" value="07540167608" maxlength="11" id="txtMobileNumber" class="phonenumber number" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <select name="ctl00$MainContent$OrderTabs$tbDefaultOrder$grdvHandSets$ctl02$drpType" id="drpType">
                                <option value=""></option>
                                <option value="1">New</option>
                                <option value="2">Upg</option>
                                <option selected="selected" value="3">Port</option>
                                <option value="4">Migr</option>
                                <option value="5">SOC</option>

                            </select>
                                </td><td>
                                    <select name="ctl00$MainContent$OrderTabs$tbDefaultOrder$grdvHandSets$ctl02$drpPortingFrom" id="drpPortingFrom">
                                <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
                                <option value="Vodafone">Vodafone</option>
                                <option value="O2">O2</option>
                                <option value="Three">Three</option>
                                <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
                                <option value="TMobile">TMobile</option>
                                <option value="Virgin">Virgin</option>
                                <option value="BT">BT</option>
                                <option value="CW">CW</option>
                                <option value="Tesco">Tesco</option>

                            </select>
                                </td><td>
                                    <input name="ctl00$MainContent$OrderTabs$tbDefaultOrder$grdvHandSets$ctl02$txtUsername" type="text" value="Jon" maxlength="100" id="txtUsername" class="handsetDetails" />
                                </td><td>
                                    <select name="ctl00$MainContent$OrderTabs$tbDefaultOrder$grdvHandSets$ctl02$drpUseType" id="drpUseType">
                                <option value=""></option>
                                <option selected="selected" value="1">Indivi</option>
                                <option value="2">Parent</option>
                                <option value="3">Sharer</option>

                            </select>
                                </td><td>
                                    <input name="ctl00$MainContent$OrderTabs$tbDefaultOrder$grdvHandSets$ctl02$txtTariffName" type="text" value="one net express" maxlength="100" id="txtTariffName" class="handsetDetails" />
                                </td><td>
                                    <input name="ctl00$MainContent$OrderTabs$tbDefaultOrder$grdvHandSets$ctl02$txtTariffCode" type="text" maxlength="50" id="txtTariffCode" class="handsetDetails" />
                                </td><td>
                                    <input name="ctl00$MainContent$OrderTabs$tbDefaultOrder$grdvHandSets$ctl02$txtSocName" type="text" maxlength="100" id="txtSocName" class="handsetDetails" />
                                </td><td>
                                    <input name="ctl00$MainContent$OrderTabs$tbDefaultOrder$grdvHandSets$ctl02$txtSocCode" type="text" maxlength="50" id="txtSocCode" class="handsetDetails" />
                                </td><td>
                                    <select name="ctl00$MainContent$OrderTabs$tbDefaultOrder$grdvHandSets$ctl02$drpContractTerm" id="drpContractTerm">
                                <option value=""></option>
                                <option value="60">60m</option>
                                <option selected="selected" value="36">36m</option>
                                <option value="24">24m</option>
                                <option value="18">18m</option>
                                <option value="12">12m</option>

                            </select>
                                </td><td>
                                    <input name="ctl00$MainContent$OrderTabs$tbDefaultOrder$grdvHandSets$ctl02$txtHandsetDescription" type="text" value="9300" maxlength="200" id="txtHandsetDescription" class="handsetDetails" />
                                </td><td>
                                   <select name="ctl00$MainContent$OrderTabs$tbDefaultOrder$grdvHandSets$ctl02$drpPhoneCover" id="drpPhoneCover">
                                <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
                                <option value="SIL">SIL</option>
                                <option value="GLD">GLD</option>
                                <option value="PLT">PLT</option>
                                <option value="DIA">DIA</option>

                            </select>
                                </td><td>
                                    <input name="ctl00$MainContent$OrderTabs$tbDefaultOrder$grdvHandSets$ctl02$txtPACCode" type="text" value="tel 683234" maxlength="12" id="txtPACCode" class="handsetDetails" />
                                </td><td>
                                    <input name="ctl00$MainContent$OrderTabs$tbDefaultOrder$grdvHandSets$ctl02$txtConDate" type="text" autocomplete="off" maxlength="10" id="txtConDate" class="date" />
                                </td><td>
                                   <a onclick="javascript:return confirm(&#39;Are you sure you want to delete this handset row 13189&#39;);" id="lnkDelete" href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$MainContent$OrderTabs$tbDefaultOrder$grdvHandSets$ctl02$lnkDelete&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))">
                                     X</a>
                                 </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
```

Comment: The post back is cancelled as i have put return false at the end of my function, i have a ID for the html table which is grdvHandSets unless you mean something else?

Comment: $('#grdvHandSets td.highlight').removeClass('highlight') selector is selecting only highlighted 'td's. You have chained it with the .find() method which may return nothing... removing the chain should work...

Comment: Hi iv tried what you have said but yet it does nothing?!?! iv removed  return $(this).val() == phonenumber;

Comment: Iv removed the dot i now get the word Find is underfined?

Comment: try using my code in the answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this:

```
$('#<%= BtnFindMobile.ClientID %>').click(function () {
            var phonenumber = $('#<%= txtSearchMobile.ClientID %>').val();
            $('#grdvHandSets td.highlight').removeClass('highlight'); // Clear existing highlights
            // Find matching phonenumber fields
            $('#grdvHandSets td input.phonenumber').filter(function () {
            return $(this).val() == phonenumber;
            }).
            closest('td').addClass('highlight'); // And highlight these cells
            return false;
         });
```

Comment: Thanks for much for that, its not working, i want to change the color of the text but its not currenly working at the moment, it only changes the background but ill work it out thanks for all your help on this

Comment: to change the color you just need to use the color style in the .highlight class

Comment: yeah all working fine now :D, one quick question is there a way i can change the Jquery to search the last 5 digits on the mobile phone column instead of matching the hole number?

Comment: use substring method of normal javascript on the phone number to extract last 5 digits

Comment: Iv just thought is there a way of just searching for what ever the has put in? so say i just enter 077901 and click find can i modify the above to search for any numbers that match that? because if i use Substring i cant really determin how many numbers the user will enter it could be more could be less?

Comment: that means, you want whether a phone number contains something, right? use _indexOf_ method of string (normal javascript); if it is nonzero, it is your candidate.